# pyqtgraph: flipping/rotating a scatterplot in place

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am using a circle-shaped 2D scatterplot to plot data points over a static image of a cell. The image is in a UI made with PyQt5. It seems that the data is not in the expected location: it is incorrect along the x-axis. I am trying to correct this without simply flipping the cell image.
I have tried to move the plot a few ways:

```
self.dataPlot.setRotation(value)
```

This moves the whole plot away from the object.

```
self.graphicsView.view.invertX(True)
```

This flips the entire view, including the plot, so in a relative sense, the plot is still wrong.

I want to flip the plot in-place, instead of around the 0,0 of the graphicsView. Or at least, rotate it in place, like turning the dial on a stove. How can this be done? Below is an illustration of the issue:
[image]

Comment: If all you need is reflection about the x-axis, why not invert the y values themselves?

Comment: @Basil just tried that. The whole graph moved up in the graphics view and away from the cell.

Comment: Check the y-value of the horizontal line in that circular shape relative to your data, and reflect the data around that value.

Comment: @Basil that lines does not exist in the actual plot, that is a division I made in the drawing as a visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was a two-step process unique to my situation:

First off, I needed the data to actually be flipped, so I had to call:

```
self.graphicsView.view.invertY(False)
```

This had to be "False" because it turns out that for Y in this Qt component, "True" is the default. Next, on just the image itself, I had to call:

```
imgData = np.fliplr(preImgData)
```

That got the data points properly overlayed where they need to be on the image.